# Search for text in file stored in mongo

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have many files in my mongo db. I want to retrieve only those files which contains the word "hello world". The text is not part of the name of the file but found anywhere inside(content) of the file. Does mongo provide any api for this? or should we retrieve each file from mongo and search for it in every file? Please help.

Comment: are you talking about files stored in GridFS or are you talking about documents?

Comment: @Philipp files stored in grid fs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want full text search, you can integrate mongodb with elasticsearch. See richardwilly98's mongodb-elasticsearch river https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki. For large files, you need the elasticsearch mapper attachment.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to search inside GridFS files as they are simply Binary chunks. In fact is rare that GridFS is used to store plain text files.

It's better to read those files and store them as string fields inside MongoDB.

Of course if what you're looking for is a Full Text Search engine, then a NoSQL database will not provide all the functionality and performance that, for example, the [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) would provide.

Lastly if you don't want to move the files, your application will need to read these, and search inside them.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo

Comment: I want to search for words, text inside a document. Not the name of the document. Does the above link help me in that?

Comment: No sorry. In that case see @GianPaJ answer. Indeed Solr is the way to ga!